# Does howler have a way of notifying given an interval?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, html5-audio, howler.js

Wondering if [Howler JS](https://howlerjs.com/) has a way of notifying every second?  This would be used to update a state variable that tracks how long a song has been playing for.  One way to do it is like this:

```
var sound = new Howl({
  xhr: {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
  },
  //  autoplay: true,
  loop: true,
  volume: 1,
  format: ['mp3'],
  src: [mp3],
});
sound.play();
let position: number = 0;
const s = interval(1000).subscribe((v) => {
  console.log(v);
  if (!sound.playing()) {
    s.unsubscribe();
  }
  position = sound.seek();
  console.log(position);
```

Just curious if howler has something like:

```
const interval = 1000;
song.on(interval, callback)
```

So that would call the callback until the song is done playing?

Comment: Any reason you don't use HTML `<audio>` element and `timeupdate` event?

Comment: That's the type of thing I'm looking for.  This is a completely custom UI that uses Howler to play the song, so I thought perhaps Howler would have something similar to what the `<audio>` element offers ...

Comment: No idea. AFAICT MP3 playback is supported by all modern browsers. You can omit `controls` attribute and use your custom controls for seeking, pausing, playng, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the docs](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js?tab=readme-ov-file#core), `Howler` instances have a method `.on` to listen to events. Sadly, there is no progression event or similar.

However, there is an option `html5` that can be set to `true` in order to force the use of HTML5 for playback.

A call to `Howler#play` returns the `Sound`'s ID. In your case:

```
const soundId = sound.play(); // your variable sound is an Howler instance
```

You can get the `Sound` object by calling `Howler#_soundById`.

```
const soundObj = sound._soundById(soundId);
```

You can get the HTML5 audio element by using the `Sound#_node` property (which will be an `HTMLAudioElement`).

```
const audio = soundObj._node;
```

Then you can use whatever `HTMLAudioElement` provides, including listening to [`progress` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/progress_event).

```
fromEvent(audio, "progress")
  .pipe(throttleTime(1000))
  .subscribe(event => {
    // do stuff with `audio` and `event` here
  });
```